# Como ordenar un arreglo multidimensional por campo en PHP

Tags: php, sql

Estoy tratando de ordenar el siguiente arreglo multidimensional de manera que muestre el saldo mayor hasta el saldo menor, sin perder la relación de dicho saldo con su numero de cuenta. Cada campo viene de una consulta `SQL`.

```
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($resultado as $row) {
                        //Preparacion de la consulta SQL con ultimo movimiento de N numeros de cuentas
                        $stid = $conn->prepare("SELECT CUENTA, FECHA, SALDO FROM ( SELECT G300.G300CTA AS CUENTA, MAX(G305.G305FDIA) AS FECHA, G305.G305S01 AS SALDO FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 WHERE G300.G300CTA = :cuenta AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID GROUP BY G300.G300CTA, G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01 ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1");
                        $stid->bindParam(':cuenta', $row['NUMERO_CUENTA'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
                        $stid->execute();
                        $answer = $stid->fetchAll();

                        foreach ($answer as $view) {
                        //¿Como puedo ordenar el siguiente arreglo?
                            $array[$i] = array(
                                $view['CUENTA']=>$view['SALDO']
                            );
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
```

La variable `$resultado` es otro array que tiene varios numeros de cuenta.

Este seria el resultado sin ordenarlo por el campo saldo:

[image: Resultado sin ordenar]

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo traes ya ordenado desde la consulta: `SELECT CUENTA, FECHA, SALDO FROM ... ORDER BY SALDO`. Así evitas voooolver a manipular los datos sólo para eso y aprovechas la optimización que ofrece el DBMS (si tienes bien los índices, claro).

Comment: @A.Cedano Porque lo que hace la consulta es traerme el saldo con la fecha más reciente, es decir, si tiene saldo en la fecha `02-02-2019` y `03-02-2019`, me devuelve la del dia `03`. Aplique lo que dices, en ordenarlo por saldo, pero me trae es el saldo mayor que encuentre  y no por la fecha, que es lo que estoy buscando.

Comment: Dado que tienes una sub-consulta, puede que le hayas puesto el `ORDER BY` donde no iba ¿? Ten en cuenta que puedes poner varios órdenes y de diversos tipos en una consulta: `ORDER BY FECHA DESC, SALDO ASC, NOMBRE ASC` es cuestión de ir poniendo cada orden según la prioridad.

Comment: Además no estás produciendo un array realmente normalizado, cuya estructura debería ser: `array (array ('cuenta'=>1, 'saldo'=>'100.99'), array ('cuenta'=>2, 'saldo'=>'99.99'), ...)` **el hecho de que hayas asignado el número de la cuenta como key es un gravísimo error**, habría que proceder a algo más complicado en ese array para establecer un orden, dado que la clave cambia en cada caso. Debes entender que un array asociativo es una estructura que ordena los datos por clave=>valor y que conviene que las claves se llamen siempre igual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solución desde SQL (recomendada)

En este caso lo más simple es que traigas tus datos ordenados en la misma consulta SQL.

Si el orden debe aplicarse en la consulta general:

```
.... WHERE ROWNUM <= 1 ORDER BY SALDO DESC
```

Si el orden debe aplicarse en la sub-consulta, en SQL puedes ordenar por varias columnas, poniendo en prioridad la primera columna por la que quieres ordenar:

```
... ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC, SALDO DESC
```

---

### Solución desde PHP

Si de todos modos quieres trabajar el orden por PHP, entonces crea un arreglo asociativo realmente normalizado. En un arreglo asociativo, **cada columna se debería llamar igual**, porque de ese modo todo se facilita, pudiendo usar funciones específicas que existen. De lo contrario tendrías que recurrir a procedimientos complicados.

Para hacerlo, PDO tiene de hecho una bandera específica.

Sólo basta con esto:

```
$answer = $stid->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Ya tienes tus datos en `$answer`, no manipules más. Se producirá un array más o menos así:

```
$answer=  array(
                    array('CUENTA'=>1,'SALDO'=>'19.01'),
                    array('CUENTA'=>2,'SALDO'=>'11.01'),
                    array('CUENTA'=>3,'SALDO'=>'10.01'),
                    array('CUENTA'=>4,'SALDO'=>'18.01'),
                    array('CUENTA'=>5,'SALDO'=>'15.01')
                );
```

Eso es un **array asociativo**, donde cada valor va ligado a su columna.

> Ahora, ¡magia! PHP tiene una función llamada **[`multi_sort`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)**
>   para ordenar este array por la clave `SALDO`.

Veamos, es una sola línea de código, sin procedimientos oscuros:

```
array_multisort (array_column($answer, 'SALDO'), SORT_DESC, $answer);
print_r($answer);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CUENTA] => 1
            [SALDO] => 19.01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CUENTA] => 4
            [SALDO] => 18.01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CUENTA] => 5
            [SALDO] => 15.01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CUENTA] => 2
            [SALDO] => 11.01
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [CUENTA] => 3
            [SALDO] => 10.01
        )

)
```

### Resumen

Hay que ser coherentes cuando se programa. Las cosas son a veces fáciles, pero uno las hace complicadas.

Precisamente **te has complicado la vida** al hacer esto:

```
                    foreach ($answer as $view) {
                    //¿Como puedo ordenar el siguiente arreglo?
                        $array[$i] = array(
                            $view['CUENTA']=>$view['SALDO']
                        );
                        $i++;
                    }
```

No solamente **vuelves a manipular los datos sin necesidad**, sino que en esa manipulación **rompes el array asociativo que PDO crea, para crear un array arbitrario donde cada vez cambias la clave `SALDO` por el número de cuenta**, creando además un nuevo array (dando más carga al servidor).

Y no sólo, sino que para trabajar eso luego, vas a tener que recurrir de nuevo a procedimientos complicados **manipulando por ¡tercera vez los datos!, cuando debiste dejarlos tranquilos, tal y como estaban en `$answer`**.

Generalmente los lenguajes de programación tienen métodos optimizados para cada cosa, por eso conviene siempre usarlos. La programación es como la vida real: si el árbol es grande, no puedes intentar podarlo con una tijera de cortar papel, ¿no?

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de un array similar al propuesto:

```php
//Array propuesto
$arraySuperior= array(
        0=>array(1024004598 => '503.83'),
        1=>array(1024004937 => '176957.18'),
        2=>array(1024004945 => '179961.32'),
        3=>array(1024005066 => '4977087.73'),
        4=>array(1044010419 => '93272.33'),
        5=>array(1044010690 => '1560198.06')
);
```

Después introduje todos los elementos en un array nuevo para ordenarlos más adelante.

```
$arrayResultado=array();

foreach($arraySuperior as $array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
            $arrayResultado[$key]=$value;
    }
}
```

Una vez hecho esto, se obtiene un array similar al siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [1024004598] => 503.83
    [1024004937] => 176957.18
    [1024004945] => 179961.32
    [1024005066] => 4977087.73
    [1044010419] => 93272.33
    [1044010690] => 1560198.06
)
```

El cual ordené por los valores de las claves de la siguiente manera:

```
asort($arrayResultado);
```

El resultado es un array (**$arrayResultado**) parecido al siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [1024004598] => 503.83
    [1044010419] => 93272.33
    [1024004937] => 176957.18
    [1024004945] => 179961.32
    [1044010690] => 1560198.06
    [1024005066] => 4977087.73
)
```

Este resultado puedes convertirlo en un array parecido al que tenías al principio si lo deseas de la siguiente manera:

```
$arrayNuevo=array();
foreach($arrayResultado as $key=>$value){
        array_push($arrayNuevo,array($key=>$value));
}
```

De esta forma se obtiene un array (**$arrayNuevo**) con una estructura parecida a la propuesta en un principio, ya ordenada por el valor de las claves:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1024004598] => 503.83
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1044010419] => 93272.33
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1024004937] => 176957.18
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1024004945] => 179961.32
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1044010690] => 1560198.06
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [1024005066] => 4977087.73
        )

)
```