# Agrupar Array PHP por valor

Tags: php, array

Quisiera agrupar mi arrayAmigos por edad

```
$ArrayAmigos = array (
    array("nombre"=>"Pedro", "edad"=>20, "telefono"=>1234), 
    array("nombre"=>"Carlos", "edad"=>15, "telefono"=>5678), 
    array("nombre"=>"Susana", "edad"=>20, "telefono"=>4321), 
    array("nombre"=>"Carmen", "edad"=>19, "telefono"=>8765)
);


foreach ($ArrayAmigos as $Amigo) 
{

echo "<br>";
echo $Amigo[edad];
echo "<br>";
echo $Amigo[nombre];
echo "<br>";

}
```

Quedando asi;

- 20
  Pedro
  Susana
- 15
  Carlos
- 19
  Carmen

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que he buscado información y no encuentro, he encontrado con base de datos pero no estoy manejando base de datos.

Comment: Revisa el apartado: **Solución desde PHP** en la [respuesta aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/259349/29967). Con algo como esto: `array_multisort (array_column($ArrayAmigos, 'edad'), SORT_DESC, $ArrayAmigos);` lograrías ordenarlo por `edad`. También puedes revisar la documentación de [`array_multisort`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-multisort.php).

Comment: @A.Cedano Creo que el OP no busca una ordenación, si no una agrupación. Es decir, que si en el `array` existen dos amigos de la misma edad, se quede una sola linea con algo similar a: `array("nombre"=>"Pedro Juan", "edad"=>20, "telefono"=>1234 4567), ` o a `array("nombre"=>array('Pedro', 'Juan'), "edad"=>20, "telefono"=>array(1234, 5678)), `

Comment: Tienes razón @phpMyGuel. Reabierta. Gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 5):

Si sólo te interesa los nombres agrupados por edad puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
$ArrayAmigos = array (
    array("nombre"=>"Pedro", "edad"=>20, "telefono"=>1234), 
    array("nombre"=>"Carlos", "edad"=>15, "telefono"=>5678), 
    array("nombre"=>"Susana", "edad"=>20, "telefono"=>4321), 
    array("nombre"=>"Carmen", "edad"=>19, "telefono"=>8765)
);

$friendsByAge=array();
foreach ($ArrayAmigos as $k => &$amigo) {
    $friendsByAge[$amigo['edad']][$k] = $amigo['nombre'];
}
```

Aquí se crea un array `$friendsByAge` agrupando los datos por la clave `edad`. En la parte de la derecha del bucle sólo se recoge el nombre, porque es el dato que interesa.

Luego, puedes construir una lista u otra cosa leyendo `$friendsByAge` de este modo:

```
$mList="<ul>";
foreach ($friendsByAge as $k=>$item){
    $mList.="<li>$k</li>".implode(', ',$item)."<br /><br />";
}
$mList.="</ul>";
echo $mList;
```

**Salida:**

```html
<ul>
  <li>20</li>Pedro, Susana<br /><br />
  <li>15</li>Carlos<br /><br />
  <li>19</li>Carmen<br /><br />
</ul>
```

---

Si te interesa guardar todos los datos como el teléfono, puedes crear un nuevo array agrupado por edades conservando todas las claves y sus valores, menos la clave `edad` con algo como esto:

```
$friendsByAge=array();

foreach ($ArrayAmigos as $k => $amigo) {
    $edad=$amigo["edad"];
    unset($amigo['edad']);
    $friendsByAge[$edad][] = $amigo;
}
```

Y luego para crear tu lista leerías el array así:

```
$mList="<ul>";
foreach ($friendsByAge as $k=>$amigos){    
    $mList.="<li>$k</li>";
    foreach ($amigos as $amigo){
        $mList.="\t$amigo[nombre] \t$amigo[telefono]<br />";
    }
    $mList.="<br />";
}
$mList.="</ul>";
echo $mList;
```

**Salida:**

```html
<ul>
  <li>20</li> Pedro 1234<br /> Susana 4321<br /><br />
  <li>15</li> Carlos 5678<br /><br />
  <li>19</li> Carmen 8765<br /><br />
</ul>
```

Otra forma de lectura sería:

```
$mList="<ul>";

    foreach ($friendsByAge as $k=>$amigos){    
        $mList.="<li>$k</li>";
        foreach ($amigos as $amigo){
            foreach ($amigo as $k=>$v) {
                $mList.="\t$k: $v";
            }
            $mList.="<br />";
        }
        $mList.="<br />";
    }
    $mList.="</ul>";
    echo $mList;
```

**Salida:**

```html
<ul>
  <li>20</li> nombre: Pedro telefono: 1234<br /> nombre: Susana telefono: 4321<br /><br />
  <li>15</li> nombre: Carlos telefono: 5678<br /><br />
  <li>19</li> nombre: Carmen telefono: 8765<br /><br />
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener las personas para cada edad (luego puedes extraer su nombre o lo que sea):

```
<?php

// This function is from php.net: 
// https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php#103905
function array_value_recursive($key, array $arr)
{
    $val = array();
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k) use($key, &$val){
        if($k == $key) array_push($val, $v);
    });

    return count($val) > 1 ? $val : array_pop($val);
}

function getPeopleByAge($arrPeople)
{
    $arrAges = array_unique(array_value_recursive('edad', $arrPeople));

    $arrPeopleGroupingByAge = [];
    foreach ($arrAges as $age) {
        $arrPeopleGroupingByAge[$age] = getPeopleForAgeOf($age, $arrPeople);
    }

    return $arrPeopleGroupingByAge;
}

function getPeopleForAgeOf($age, $arrPeople)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($arrPeople as $personData) {
        foreach ($personData as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === 'edad' && $value === $age) {
                $result[] = $personData;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}


/**
 * Tests
 * 
 */

$ArrayAmigos = array (
    array("nombre"=>"Pedro",  "edad"=>20, "telefono"=>1234), 
    array("nombre"=>"Carlos", "edad"=>15, "telefono"=>5678), 
    array("nombre"=>"Susana", "edad"=>20, "telefono"=>4321), 
    array("nombre"=>"Carmen", "edad"=>19, "telefono"=>8765)
);

// Traza:
print_r(getPeopleByAge($ArrayAmigos));
```

La salida sería:

```
Array
(
    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nombre] => Pedro
                    [edad] => 20
                    [telefono] => 1234
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [nombre] => Susana
                    [edad] => 20
                    [telefono] => 4321
                )

        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nombre] => Carlos
                    [edad] => 15
                    [telefono] => 5678
                )

        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nombre] => Carmen
                    [edad] => 19
                    [telefono] => 8765
                )

        )

)
```

#### Explicación

Esta solución se basa en obtener las edades de todas las personas del grupo y filtrarlas para que no haya repeticiones:

```
$arrAges = array_unique(array_value_recursive('edad', $arrPeople));
```

Seguidamente se crean grupos por edad: se recorren las edades (que no se repiten en este caso) y para cada edad comprueba cada persona, si tiene esa edad la guarda en el grupo de edad.