# Agrupar correctamente un select en mysql / php

Tags: php, mysql

Hola tengo un ranking de usuarios y utilizando el siguiente select mysql me muestra correctamente los primeros 10 usuarios que han respondido mejor a las preguntas que han completado, una vez terminado el cuestionario.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY correctas DESC LIMIT 10";

$r1 = mysqli_query($link5, $sql);

while($articulo2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1)){  

}
```

Pero lo que estoy necesitando ahora y no me esta saliendo es saber  en que posicion del ranking esta este usuario mienatras esta completando el cuestionario.

Para eso necesitaria ordenar todos los id por cantidad de mejor respuesta correctas y luego averiguar en que id a quedado el usuario que esta respondiendo, de esta forma obtendria el ranking que estoy necesitando, si alguien me podria dar una mano, se lo agradeceria. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la consulta que planteas obtienes los datos ordenados, sí posteriormente dentro del while puedes generar un array asociativo con los datos de la consulta más la posición del ranking, algo como:

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY correctas";
$r1 = mysqli_query($link5, $sql);

$data = [];
$pos_ranking = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1)){
  $item_data = array();
  $item_data["pos_ranking"] = $pos_ranking;
  $item_data["usuario"] = $row["usuario"];
  
  $data[] = $item_data;
  $pos_ranking += 1;
}

print_r($data);
foreach($data as $d){
    echo $d[“usuario”];
    echo “<br>”;
    echo $d[“pos_ranking”];
    if ($usuario_buscado == $d[“usuario”]){
       $posicion_buscada = $d[“pos_ranking”];
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por su ayuda, pero este codigo me muestra en pantalla todos las posiciones y yo solo necesito uno que seria el del usuario, como debo proceder.

Comment: es decir, agregando el siguiente echo:

Comment: echo "$item_data['usuario']";

Comment: me muestra solo el ultimo usuario y no el que yo necesito

Comment: El array resultante con toda la información lo tienes en $data, por ejemplo, $data[1][“usuario”], $data[1][“pos_ranking”], haz print_r($data) después del while y verás la estructura. El último usuario lo podías obtener con $data[count($data)-1][“usuario”]

Comment: ok, disculpeme pero si yo quiero un usuario en particular saber en que posicion esta como debo realizarlo?.

Comment: He añadido después del print_r($data), un bucle foreach para que veas toda la información.

Comment: hasta aqui esta todo perfecto, pero si necesito saber en que ranking esta un determinado usuario como lo averiguo?. esta es la informacion que yo necesito, espero que me entienda. gracias.

Comment: Dentro del foreach puedes comprobar el usuario que quieras con un condicional y haciendo la comprobación. Lo añado a la respuesta.

Comment: Excelente, ahora si me funciona bien el script, ha sido muy amable. desde ya muchas gracias por su amabilidad. saludos

Comment: disculpeme nuevamente, estoy probando el escript y no me lo esta ordenando por cantidad de respuestas correctas, pareciera que me lo ordena mas bien por fecha, como se podria solucionar. gracias.

Comment: En $data, el primer elemento $data[0][“correctas”] es el número mayor de respuestas correctas, ya que al construir la variable, es el primero que se ha añadido.

Comment: disculpe que no lo entiendo, que tendria que hacer para solucionarlo?.

Comment: $data está ordenada por el número de respuestas correctas, ya que lo hemos construido a partir de la consulta que ya nos devolvía en ese orden. Puedes ordenar el array asociativo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259330/como-ordenar-un-arreglo-multidimensional-por-campo-en-php

Comment: muy amable. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Conociendo el `id_usuario`, supongamos que sea `1`, te propongo simplemente contar los usuarios que hayan obtenido mayor puntuación que el interesado:

```
$n_orden = $link5->query("
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios
      WHERE correctas>(
        SELECT correctas FROM usuarios
          WHERE id_usuario=".$id_usuario."
      );
")->fetch_row()[0];
```

Comment: gracias por su ayuda, pero no logro hacer que funcione.

Comment: Por favor, modifica tu pregunta con lo que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte. ¿En qué variable tienes el `id_usuario`?

Comment: el id_usuario lo tengo como usuario solamente, he cambiado el 1 por la variable, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: despues de este select tengo que hacer un while?

Comment: Te he modificado la respuesta para que veas cómo hacerlo desde PHP

Comment: estoy intentando y no logro hacer que funcione, disculpeme que le pregunte, despues de esto tengo que realizar un while?